# unable to clear this error - ENOTEMPTY while installing Expo CLI

Tags: react-native, expo

following is the error
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/niharsetia/.npm/_logs/2021-03-06T06_47_36_684Z-debug.log

Comment: Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384138/im-trying-to-reinstall-expo-cli-package-globally-with-the-command-sudo-npm-inst

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to reinstall expo-cli package globally with the command sudo npm install --g expo-cli note that I try --force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384138/im-trying-to-reinstall-expo-cli-package-globally-with-the-command-sudo-npm-inst)

Answer (score 2):

delete /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli and try again with sudo npm install -g expo-cli