# npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY npm ERR! syscall rename

Tags: react-native, npm

when I try to initialize a react-native project I am getting this error.  Anyone know how to resolve this please help

i am using mac

```
Need to install the following packages:
  react-native
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/react-native
npm ERR! dest /Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.react-native-QIQKGFeg
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/react-native' -> '/Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.react-native-QIQKGFeg'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_logs/2022-02-16T15_54_46_715Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 8):

where it says...

directory not empty, rename '/Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/react-native' -> '/Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.react-native-QIQKGFeg'

delete the file after the arrow and try again

rm -rf '/Users/codelanticdeveloper/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.react-native-QIQKGFeg'

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting all the files in the node modules that end with a similar names, like '*-QIQKGFeg'
I did it manually and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and fixed it by:

1. Deleting the problematic Expo files here per the instructions here [I'm trying to reinstall expo-cli package globally with the command sudo npm install --g expo-cli note that I try --force](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66384138/14755660)
2. In the terminal, running `nvm install 16.14.0` (this will download the correct Node.js LTS release that is required by Expo)
3. In the terminal, running `brew install watchman` (this is required by Expo)
4. In the terminal, running `npm install --global expo-cli` (globally downloading Expo again)
5. In the terminal, running `expo init my-app` to finally create the new app successfully!